# Session timed Out in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-timeout

I searched many sites and including **Stackoverflow**, about using session timed out in MVC, but all sites and code shows only part of the code which is used in WebConfig, but it doesn't shows where in webconfig needed to be filled

I am developed a Application and now I want to add session timed out after 5 mins if the application is idle, many have stated to use Client Side and Server side too, I am little bit confused where to use it. 
and I have found from stackoverflow following code which can be used in WebConfig

```
 <system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

my question is which webconfig and where exactly that to be added ?? **because in MVC I have 2 webconfig file** one in View and another in main project, I have tried applying in both webconfig, just next to the "configuration" like this

```
 <configuration> 
     <system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
</system.web>
  </configuration>
```

and it generates error message, so please let me know how can I use Session timed out for this application

**UPDATED**

Thanks for all your replies, I have applied all the code below, and have attached screen shot of error message please check it and let me know what I am doing wrong
1) if I use the below code from i.e.

```
  <system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

under  in main web config then gets error message as below pic
[image: on main webconfig]

2) if i used same code on webconfig under views, i get this error pic
[image: on view webconfig]

along with that I am attaching a image file of both of my webconfig files

->[image: in View WebConfig]

->[image: in main Webconfig]

hope I have shared more info, ask me if I am missing out something

**UPDATE2**

**main webconfig**

```
<configuration>
```

```
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
  <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null" />
    <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </sectionGroup>
</sectionGroup>
```

```
<businessObjects>
  <crystalReports>
    <rptBuildProvider>
      <add embedRptInResource="true" />
    </rptBuildProvider>
    <crystalReportViewer>
      <add key="ResourceUri" value="../crystalreportviewers13" />
    </crystalReportViewer>
  </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

```
<add name="webPortalConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=mysys-021\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LIS_MHL_LIVE;User ID=sa;Password=cspl#" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="LISConnectionString" connectionString="User ID=sa;Password=cspl#; Data Source=mysys-021\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=LIS_MHL_LIVE;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304"/>
  <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/></assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting.  Are you sure you do not already have a `<system.web>` section?

Comment: Thankyou for notifying me about <system.Web>, in main Webconfig I don have this, but it doesn't have </system.web> !! along with that I have entered this "  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />" within system.web and waited for 3 mins, to check it works or not, but still no go, it acts normal

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add this in your main web.config :-

```
<configuration>  
  ...  
  <system.web>  
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />  
  </system.web>  
  ...  
</configuration>
```

SESSION STATE SETTINGS By default ASP.NET uses cookies to identify which requests belong to a particular session. If cookies are not available, a session can be tracked by adding a session identifier to the URL. To disable cookies, set sessionState cookieless="true".

Need more knowledge about this, follow the below link:-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx

Hope this will help you.

**EDITED:-**
You can just place multiple web.config file in the sub-directory and ASP.NET will override any settings you change in that directory. 
Mostly, web.config in the Views directory just has one significant entry, which blocks direct access:

```
<add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
```

This is so someone cannot manually try to go to http://www.yoursite.com/views/main/index.aspx and load the page outside the MVC pipeline.

**>>** Here after looking at your config and error message I come to a conclusion that-
You are using configSections tag in both the config (in two places.) and that is the reason you are getting this error.

**EDITED-2**:-
I saw your comment and think you should have a look at this page :)
[Format of ASP.NET Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

And for **how to place 2 webconfig in sub-directory** :-
You should check out [Configuration Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbwsx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbwsx8s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your reply I have attached and edited above post, and I tried as you stated but still gets error message, attached a pic

Comment: appreciate your observation, Yes there is 2 configsections, and how to place 2 webconfig in sub-directory and where should i add above code, could you briefly explain it , so that I can understand better ?

Comment: i have one question I have a tag which came when I created project i.e. <system.web> but I don't see closing tag of same!!, is it fine or does that has any issue with this ??

Comment: @Manjuboyz Yes it will have an issue. :D  Each and every tag should have its respective closing tag in xml. I think that's why your session is also not working.

Comment: Atlast I found,closing tag of system.web which was present at end of the longest line which I didn't saw and added the code, now I don't know the session is working or not, because i have given time limit of 1 min, and waited for 5 mins, and tried to use the application, and it is working asusual rather than, doing something about the session!!,is there any trigger which notifies me that session is working fine ??

Comment: @Manjuboyz Glad to hear your application is working now and you found the closing tag :) . For the session- I think you are messing with some session state setting. Try learning it from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
Because my friend everything cannot be spoon fed. Hope my responses and feedback have helped you to over come from problem you were having. If so please vote and mark this as answer so that other can get help too. :) Happy coding!!

Comment: issue is still not fixed!! and yes once this is fixed will definitely marked as answer, will do some R&D about this and try to fix this and will get back, if any one got any other answers let me know ,will be back with answer, thanks for all efforts people has given,appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

in your Web.config try with this:

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="5" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

as of the MSDN says, The default  element is not explicitly configured in the Machine.config file or in the root Web.config file. However, it is the default configuration that is returned by the application.

```
<sessionState 
   mode="InProc" 
   stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" 
   stateNetworkTimeout="10" 
   sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
   sqlCommandTimeout="30" 
   customProvider="" 
   cookieless="UseCookies" 
   cookieName="ASP.NET_SessionId" 
   timeout="20" 
   allowCustomSqlDatabase="false" 
   regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" 
   partitionResolverType="" 
   useHostingIdentity="true">
   <providers>
      <clear />
   </providers>
</sessionState>
```

please read full MSDN reference [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should add that section into **main web.config** file. View's web.config file is only for views.

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
</system.web>
```

And make sure you have only one `system.web` tag in your web.config file. If it is already there than only write `<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I even tried this, but its not working !!

Comment: still you're getting error in web.config? or something else?

Comment: Yep, I still getting error message as posted the pic above, when used in both webconfig's, I am using MVC is there anything to do with that(i don't know) ??

Comment: Just copy paste main web.config file in the question, I'll put the whole into my project and debug.

Comment: I have added code of my webconfig,there is must be one para missed, i added it but it is not accepting it, I am pasting it here, if anybody able to edit to that post, then please do it, here is the code with double quotes " <add name="LISConnectionString" connectionString="User ID=sa;Password=csplsa#; Data Source=CSPLNB-021\SQLEXPRESS;INITIAL CATALOG=LIS_MHL_LIVE;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />"

Comment: <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true" />
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000" />
      <add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000" />
  </appSettings> <system.web>
    
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

Comment: Atlast I found,closing tag of system.web which was present at end of the longest line which I didn't saw and added the code, now I don't know the session is working or not, because i have given time limit of 1 min, and waited for 5 mins, and tried to use the application, and it is working asusual rather than, doing something about the session!!,is there any trigger which notifies me that session is working fine ??